# Importing android_core failed

Tags: android-core, rosjava, android

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Error on opening old working android_core project in Android Studio 0.3.4 (also in 0.2.0)
Error on importing new android_core project in Android Studio 0.3.4 (also in 0.2.0)

Till last week I was able to use the android_core project which I imported to Android Studio 0.3.1.
But when I opened it again yesterday (09.11)(in Android Studio 0.3.1) I was getting errors. On Sunday (10.11) I cloned a new android_core from the Github but I could not import it to Android Studio 0.3.1 (no error in catkin_make).
I upgraded to Android Studio 0.3.4 (also to 0.3.5) but the same errors on opening the old working android_core and also for importing a new one.

[Error on importing]
"**Resolver error
Could not find any version that matches org.ros.rosjava_bootstr
ap:gradle_plugins:[0.1,0.2).

Required by:
:android_core:unspecified**"

[Error on opening an old android_core]
**"Gradle 'android_core' project refresh failed:
Could not execute build using Gradle distribution 'http://ser.../gradle-1.8-all.zip'

A problem occurred configuring project ':android_acm_serial'.

A problem occurred configuring project ':android_acm_serial'.

Failed to notify project evaluation listener.

A problem occurred configuring project ':android_honeycomb_mr2'.

Failed to notify project evaluation listener.

A problem occurred configuring project ':android_gingerbread_mr1'.

Failed to notify project evaluation listener.

Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':android_gingerbread_mr1:_DebugCompile'.
Could not find any version that matches org.ros.rosjava_messages:sensor_msgs:1.10.+.

Required by:
org.ros.android_core:android_gingerbread_mr1:0.1.0"**

Then I degraded to Android Studio 0.2.0 tried again but it gave again the same errors.

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 and new to ROS. Is there any solution for the above errors ?
Thanks, dtc.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/100271/importing-android_core-failed/) by [dtc](https://answers.ros.org/users/8716/dtc/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2013-11-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Should use "./studio.sh" instead of "sudo ./studio.sh"

---

Originally posted by [dtc](https://answers.ros.org/users/8716/dtc/) with karma: 41 on 2013-11-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Did you source setup.bash?

Make sure you do the following steps:

1. catkin_make the workspcae
2. source setup.bash
3. run android studio from the shell

When building from android studio, it just directly uses gradle. The gradle setup for the rosjava stacks is using some of the ros environment variables so you'll need to source the setup.bash.

---

Originally posted by [Daniel Stonier](https://answers.ros.org/users/51/daniel-stonier/) with karma: 3170 on 2013-11-14

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dtc](https://answers.ros.org/users/8716/dtc/) on 2013-11-16**:
Yes I done that,
catkin_make //Build successful
source /devel/setup.bash
sudo ./studio.sh
It is helpful if you can confirm that the Import is still working.
I am using the link
http://wiki.ros.org/android/Tutorials/hydro/Installation - Ros Development Environment.
Now planing to reinstall everything

**Comment by [dtc](https://answers.ros.org/users/8716/dtc/) on 2013-11-17**:
Same errors even after reinstalling Ubuntu, Ros Hydro, rosjava (used ros-shadow-fixed) and AndroidStudio-0.3.2 (catkin_make successful). Is there any other way than the "5.1 Fat Workspace" (or a better explanation for "5.2 Diet Workspace") for using ROS in Android, may be with Eclipse? <Thanks, DTC>

**Comment by [dtc](https://answers.ros.org/users/8716/dtc/) on 2013-11-19**:
I should use "./studio.sh" instead of "sudo ./studio.sh".
"sudo ./studio.sh" gives the errors which I mentioned above.
Link,
http://wiki.ros.org/android |
http://rosjava.github.io/android_core/latest/  |
http://wiki.ros.org/android/Tutorials/hydro/Installation%20-%20Ros%20Development%20Environment

**Comment by [Daniel Stonier](https://answers.ros.org/users/51/daniel-stonier/) on 2013-11-19**:
Glad to hear you worked it out.